# PListBuddy Fails When Called From ant

Tags: xcode, ant, automation, plist

I have a build script that pulls the old version out of the plist for an iOs product, outputs it, then updates the plist. The two commands are

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print CFBundleVersion ${LocationOfPList}
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Set :CFBundleVersion ${Version} ${LocationOfPList}
```

Run from the command line (with the version and the proper PList file location), everything is fine. Run from ant as

```
<exec executable="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy" 
  outputproperty="CurrentVersion"
  errorproperty="PListError">
  <arg value="-c"/>
  <arg value ="Print :CFBundleVersion"/>
  <arg value="${LocationOfPList}"/>
</exec> 

<echo message="Fetched the last version in the plist: ${CurrentVersion}" />

<!-- Set the plist to the current build number -->
<exec executable="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy"
  outputproperty="PListOutput"
  errorproperty="PListError"
>       
  <arg value="-c"/>
  <arg value ="Set :CFBundleVersion ${Version}" />              
  <arg value=" ${LocationOfPList}"/>
</exec>

<echo message="Output: ${PListOutput}"/>
<echo message="Errors: ${PListError}"/>
<echo message="Old version number: ${CurrentVersion} New Version Number: ${Version}" />
```

Results in some strange behavior. The first command works, the second fails. This ant script is running as the same user as the command line example. The output I see is:

```
[echo] Fetched the last version in the plist: 3.0.0
[exec] Result: 1
[echo] Output: File Doesn't Exist, Will Create:  /Users/macbuild/iPhone/branches/anttest/iChime/Program-Info.plist
[echo] Errors: 
[echo] Old version number: 3.0.0 New Version Number: anttest
```

The plist isn't updated, and the only hit is a return code of 1. I'm the release engineer - I don't know xcode. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a leading space just before the plist location in the set command:

```
 <!--        v -->
 <arg value=" ${LocationOfPList}"/>
```

It's one of those invisible errors - you might notice two spaces between "Will Create:" and "/Users" in the error message.
Remove the space and it should work.

Also, the `PListError` property is set to an empty string by the first exec, and Ant properties are immutable, hence no error text for the second exec.

Comment: Good catch, but actually it's not that. I did a bad copy and paste job. The line in my ant script is ${PlistBuddy}, and I copied the property (defined in a shared property file) in to show what executable I was using for the question - I just missed deleting the $ and }. I'll fix it in the question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Updated.  Minor typo again, but reproducible here.

Comment: @Feasoron - take a number... ;)